# Swapping images with jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Im trying to change a jQuery tabs script to fit my needs, i swapped the tabs out for images and i added jQuery code to change the images on hover and click.

But my code isint working, when you press one of the images the tab should become active and the image should stay changed but it always goes back to the original.

Here my code:

```
function resetTabs(){
$("#container > div").hide(); 
        $("#tabs a").attr("id","");     
    }
    var myUrl = window.location.href;
    var myUrlTab = myUrl.substring(myUrl.indexOf("#"));      
    var myUrlTabName = myUrlTab.substring(0,4); 

    (function(){
        $("#container > div").hide(); 
        $("#tabs li:first a").attr("id","current"); 
        $("#container > div:first").fadeIn(); 
        $("#tabs a").on("click",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "current"){
             return       
            }
            else{             
            resetTabs();
            $(this).attr("id","current"); 
            $($(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); 
            }
        });

        for (i = 1; i <= $("#tabs li").length; i++) {
      if (myUrlTab == myUrlTabName + i) {
          resetTabs();
          $("a[name='"+myUrlTab+"']").attr("id","current"); 
          $(myUrlTab).fadeIn(); //      
      }
    }
})()  

$(function(){
$('.hoverfun').on('mouseenter mouseout', function(){
  var original = $(this).attr('src');
  var replacement = $(this).data('hoverimg');       
  $(this).attr('src', replacement).data('hoverimg', original);
    });
});

$(function(){
$('.hoverfun').on('click', function(){
  var original = $(this).attr('src');
  var replacement = $(this).data('downimg');
  $(this).attr('src', replacement).data('downimg', original);
    });
});

<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab1"><img class="hoverfun" src="images/img1.png" data-hoverimg="images/img2.png" data-downimg="images/img3.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab2"><img class="hoverfun" src="images/img1.png" data-hoverimg="images/img2.png" data-downimg="images/img3.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab3"><img class="hoverfun" src="images/img1.png" data-hoverimg="images/img2.png" data-downimg="images/img3.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab4"><img class="hoverfun" src="images/img1.png" data-hoverimg="images/img2.png" data-downimg="images/img3.png"></a></li>
```

I know its messy, but if anyone could take a look for me i would appreciate it :)

Comment: How about putting it into a jsfiddle?

Comment: Why don't you use css to use images as background for tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what it is you want to accomplish, but maybe this will help.

You could add a class with `.addClass()` to `.hoverfun` when you click it. Something like `active`.

Then you could check and see if the element has `active` with `.hasClass()` and ignore the mouseover effects in case it does.

```
$(function () {
    $('.hoverfun').on('mouseenter mouseout', function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            var original = $(this).attr('src');
            var replacement = $(this).data('hoverimg');
            $(this).attr('src', replacement).data('hoverimg', original);
        }
    });

    $('.hoverfun').on('click', function () {
        $('.active').each(function() {
            var o1 = $(this).attr('src');
            var o2 = $(this).data('hoverimg');
            var o3 = $(this).data('downimg');

            $(this).attr('src', o2).data('downimg', o1).data('hoverimg', o3).removeClass('active');
        });

        var original = $(this).attr('src');
        var replacement = $(this).data('downimg');
        $(this).attr('src', replacement).data('downimg', original).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3hqgh/1/

Comment: Oh man, thats beautiful! Thank you so much - one more thing, if you allready have an active photo and press the other photo the previous active photo should get disabled, sorry if my english is horrible :)

Comment: Sure thing. Updated my answer above.

Comment: Man! Thanks alot, was really cracking my head over this one! You sir are a gentleman and a scholar

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept the answer with the check mark to the left if it was considered an answer to your question.

Comment: Done and done, one more thing master - i tried myself but unfortunately im rubish with jquery.. i tried to add a class to one of the image so its allready active when the page loads but mine is buggy u got an idea?

Comment: It may be because you aren't actually doing something with the active class until you move your mouse over a tab. This whole section `if (!$(this).hasClass( ...` needs to be run on document ready as well. Also, your active buttons might flicker since they are set up with javascript on page load.